# Compare two xml with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have created two XML files namely XML1 and XML2 Which contain Some Employee ID in this case it is Test1,2,3 apparently
Where I compare both the XML file and find the difference between them

XML1:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee ID="Test1" />
    <Employee ID="Test2" />
    <Employee ID="Test3" />
<Employees>
```

XML2:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee ID="Testing1" />
    <Employee ID="Testing2" />
    <Employee ID="Test3" />
<Employees>
```

C#:

```cs
public string CompareXML(XmlTextReader xmlDocument1, XmlTextReader xmlDocument2)
{
    var diff = new XmlDiff 
    {
        IgnoreComments = true,
        IgnorePI = true,
        IgnoreWhitespace = true,
        IgnoreChildOrder = true,
        Algorithm = XmlDiffAlgorithm.Precise,
    };

    var wString = new StringWriter();
    var xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(wString);
    
    xmltw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    
    var status = diff.Compare(xmlDocument1, xmlDocument2, xmltw);

    difference = wString.ToString();
    xmltw.Close();

    return difference;
}
```

Basically, I'm comparing two xml files and finding the difference(`using Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch`), and getting the desired output. But,

What I get

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="11148343190120608020" options="IgnoreChildOrder IgnoreComments IgnorePI IgnoreWhitespace " fragments="no" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
  <xd:node match="2">
    <xd:node match="4">
      <xd:change match="@ID">Test1</xd:change>
    </xd:node>
    <xd:node match="1">
      <xd:change match="@ID">Test2</xd:change>
    </xd:node>
  </xd:node>
</xd:xmldiff>
```

What I need

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee ID="Test1" />
    <Employee ID="Test2" />
<Employees>
```

Comment: What if `Test3` came before the others (ie the difference is in the ordering)? Why don't `Testing1` and `Testing2` show as a difference?

Comment: Nope Test3 doesn't come first. As diff.Compare(xmlDocument1, xmlDocument2, xmltw); xmlDocument1 Checks the difference  in xmlDocument2 so it posts the Difference in xmlDocument. So you got some clarity.

Comment: I think this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Is comparing xml your actual objective? or is it just the way you think it would solve it. What I mean is that you don't tell what you are trying to achieve (comparing data sets or any business rules). I guess you'll probably end in a simple code that loads the 2 lists, and compare the list in memory to find some data

Comment: Comparing xml is objective and find difference that difference need to be in format so it can be used other way.